# Delete blank rows until LastRow variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete all blank rows until the `LastRow` variable. Below you'll find my samples. The one that works **seems a serious workaround and I believe it could be shorter/quicker**, I just don't have the knowledge on how to do it.

**Works - Serious workaround**

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 to LastRow
   If Range("A" & i).value = "" then
      Range("A" & i).value = "xxxxx"
   End if
Next i

For i = 1 to LastRow
   If Range("A" & i).value = "xxxxx" then
      Range("A" & i).Delete
      i = i - 1
   End if
Next i
```

**Infinite loop**

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 to LastRow
   If Range("A" & i).value = "" then
      Range("A" & i).Delete
      i = i - 1
   End if
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all I assume you have Calculation set to Manual

Second you have a for loop that will 1=i+1 and you do i=i-1 thus i=i+1-1 infinite loop. This should also happen in the working workaround (same error).

You can For Loop with a selected step, also negative ones. As deletion shortens the range you could start at the bottom and work up now

Code looks like:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = LastRow to 1 Step -1
   If Range("A" & i).value = "" then
      Range("A" & i).Delete
   End if
Next i
```

If you want the complete row deleted use `Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete` instead.

Comment: I have calculation set to automatic. Oh I see how this works, excellent! What does `Step -1` mean?

Comment: Instead of incrementing by positive 1 it decrements the iterator.

Comment: Oh so without it, it wouldn't go 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 but generate an error/stop the for loop because i = higher than the to value?

Comment: exactly, and you can also do Step 2 or Step -10, and the For will start with the first argument and finish on or before the last one (before in case of for example `For i = 0 To 3 Step 2` It will only be 0 and 2 (the next increment to 4 will be larger then the maximum of 3)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this code but it should work (maybe with minor modification):

```
Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```